# How to send mp3 files to a mobile number ..?

Tags: data-transfer, mms

Is there any website which provides this facility to send an mp3 file as MMS to my mobile number .. The actual question is "**how to transfer the data from PC to mobile without the help of data cable and blue-tooth**" thanx for the help in advance ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your phone company and phone model you can email your phone the file. When I had verizon my email was phone#@vzw.com. I know I could attach pictures but I never tried mp3's,

Comment: ohk.. I see .. thanx for answering ...